# AngularJs - How to animate only the width of something?

Tags: animation, angularjs

I haven't found any good examples on how to animate just the width of something in Angular with the new animation support.

I have a drawer off to the side of my app which I would like to expand/close when the user presses a button. The problem is that with ng-show, it always wants to apply "display: none" after the "leave" animation is done - I don't want that. I just want to animate the width of the drawer.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Angular animation currently works on css3 transitions so just check out your css class there you will have trasition:all just replace all with the width in the transition property

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own directive that uses jquery animation to modify the width of an element:

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('testAnimate', function() {

  return {
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      scope.$watch(iAttrs.testAnimate, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        var shown = !!newValue;

        if (shown !== !!oldValue) {
          iElement.animate({
            width: shown ? '+=50px' : '-=50px'
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };

});
```

Live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Il0fq0nlWKckpilWFXC6?p=preview

Comment: Besides the fact that this is an option, i am not sure that this is a good answer, as he clearly want's to use it 'the angular way'
I'd say that adding a CSS class would be by far the better option, wouldn't it?

Comment: I may just have to do this. I can't find any other way to use the CSS3 animations and not completely hide something. I just want to adjust the width a bit.